# Copy Files from SharePoint Online using Azure Data Factory and Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api, data-ingestion

Does anyone know how to use in ADF the Microsoft Graph API over the SharePoint API?

A lot of existing documentation, including the official ADF documentation, references to SharePoint v1 API, which is now legacy.

Cannot manage to figure it out whether I need an assigned managed identity or an application within the Microsoft identity platform. Also, I cannot figure it out how to combine the official ADF documentation referencing to
[`SharePoint v1 API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory)
with the limited info on [`Microsoft Graph API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0#sharepoint-api-root-resources).

Answer (score 0):

To copy a file from SharePoint using Microsoft Graph, you can use the Graph API's `GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content` endpoint.